# Listview is so slow with line chart

Tags: android, listview, scroll, graphics, linechart

in my project I draw the line charts with different colors. (x <30 then draw pink points). Presumably, because of the controls I make to adjust the colors of the points according to the different limit lines in the graph. (almost 2000 controls)

Logic when i create line chart for every item :

```
public class PaintRegenerationChart extends View {
Paint mPaint, rectPaint;
int[] next= new int[144];
Context ctx;

public PaintRegenerationChart(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet){
    super(context,attributeSet);
    mPaint = new Paint();
    rectPaint=new Paint();
    this.ctx=context;
}

int first =91, last = 160;

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int[] next2={
            120,125,130,130,130,131,
            135,140,143,110,120,125,
            121,115,110,100,96,90,
            85,80,75,71,96,78,
            70,75,78,80,83,88,
            90,100,110,115,120,100,
            90,98,78,87,83,88,
            90,98,78,87,83,88,
            120,125,130,130,130,131,
            135,140,143,110,120,125,
            121,115,110,100,96,90,
            120,125,130,130,130,131,
            135,140,143,110,120,125,
            121,115,110,100,96,90,
            85,80,75,71,96,78,
            90,98,78,87,83,88,
            90,98,78,87,83,88,
            135,140,143,110,120,125,
            120,125,130,130,130,131,
            135,140,143,110,120,125,
            121,115,110,100,96,90,
            85,80,75,71,96,78,
            90,98,78,87,83,88,
            90,98,78,87,83,88,


    };

    next=next2;
    ArrayList<Float> xVals= new ArrayList<Float>();

    ArrayList<Integer> totalYvalues= new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int j=20; float willadd=20;

    for (int i = 0; i <143; i++) {

        int beforeValue=next[i];  int currentValue;
        currentValue= next[i+1];

        if(currentValue>beforeValue)
        {
            float todivide= currentValue - beforeValue;
            for (int w = beforeValue; w < currentValue; w += 1) {
                totalYvalues.add(w-30);
                if(todivide<4) todivide=3;
                willadd+= ((canvas.getWidth())/143+0.4)/todivide; //MATH**
                //Log.d("canvas.getwidth/143", ((canvas.getWidth())/143)+"");

                xVals.add(willadd);
            }
        }

        else
        {
            int todivide= beforeValue- currentValue ;
            for(int w=beforeValue; w>currentValue; w-=1)
            {
                totalYvalues.add(w-30);
                if(todivide<4) todivide=3;
                willadd+= ((canvas.getWidth())/143)/todivide; 
                xVals.add(willadd);
            }
        }
    }

    int ilk= totalYvalues.get(0);
    ArrayList<Integer> realY= new ArrayList<Integer>();
    realY.add(ilk);
    for(int i=0; i<totalYvalues.size()-1 ; i++)
    {

        int next= ilk- totalYvalues.get(i+1);
        next= next +ilk;


        realY.add(next);
    }
    rect();

    totalYvalues=realY;
    ArrayList<Integer> realY2= new ArrayList<Integer>();


    int i;
    for( i=0; i<totalYvalues.size() ;i++)
    {

        if(totalYvalues.get(i)>=110)
        {
            mPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.viitaButtonGreen));
        }
        else if( totalYvalues.get(i)>=80 &&  totalYvalues.get(i)<110)
        {
            mPaint.setColor(GRAY);
        }
        else if( totalYvalues.get(i)<80)
        {
            mPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        }

// here i am drawing graph with points. (for colorful line chart)

            canvas.drawCircle( xVals.get(i), totalYvalues.get(i), 3f, mPaint);
        }
    }

    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    canvas.drawCircle( xVals.get(i-5), totalYvalues.get(i-5), 19f, mPaint);
    mPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.viitaButtonGreen));
    canvas.drawCircle( xVals.get(i-5), totalYvalues.get(i-5), 15f, mPaint);

    for(int w=0 ; w<canvas.getWidth() ; w+=9) // limit lines
    {
        canvas.drawCircle( w, 110, 1f, mPaint);
        canvas.drawCircle( w, 80, 1f, mPaint);
        canvas.drawCircle( w, 50, 1f, mPaint);
    }

}
```

Scrolling is incredibly slow when I use it in a ListView.  Is there any suggestion how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you properly using the RecyclerView to prevent Android from having to create and recreate thousands of objects?

Comment: RecyclerView is fast if i do not use line chart in every item.

Comment: Without code, we can only guess as to what you are doing.

Comment: I addded codes may you help me? How to use view (created by us) in listview like above line chart properly?

Comment: Wait, you're doing a lot of calculations INSIDE of the view you want to display instead of handing it preprocessed data it can just display?

Comment: Yes, I have created the look I want here. How can I follow the path instead?
 Do you have any idea how I can create the look I want elsewhere?

Comment: These Views in a ListView are created and destroyed hundreds of times while scrolling, you have ZERO control over it and you don't want to. This means that every time you scroll, all these calculations happen over and over and over again, for no reason. What you want to do is present static data to a static representation for ListView. ListView is meant to display static data fast, not to calculate a lot while you're scrolling.

Comment: Thanks for the answer G_V. Where exactly do I have to make these calculations so that the speed does not affect negatively?

Comment: I think your best bet is to calculate everything you need to calculate, then stick it in an array? You want to hand a static dataset to your custom ListAdapter, so somewhere in your onCreate before you initiate the actual List, or even better, do the calculations on the data somewhere entirely outside of the app and just load them straight into your app from SQLite, something along those lines. I usually start a background Task that writes the preprocessed results retrieved from a webservice to SQLite as JSON with the GSON library, but that's because new data is added over time.

Comment: First of all thank you very much for the informations G_V, I will try and give feedback immediately.